# Body over navbar for small screens

Tags: html, css, menu, carousel, navbar

I'm developing a web page that has a responsive top navigation bar, and for screens with a width of less than 550px the effect of the image below is happening.

[image]

I'd like the carousel with the images to be below the navigation bar's list of links when it's expanded, just as it is when it's not expanded:

[image]

Here is my html code:

```
<header>
    <aside class="menu">
        <section class="main-content menu-content">
            <h1>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </h1>
            <div class="hamburguer">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <nav class="menu-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#init">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Serviços</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/goat.slts/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                            <img src="./assets/img/instagram.svg" alt="instagram" id="instagram-logo">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <script src="assets/js/menu.js"></script>
</header>

<main class="main">
    <section id="init">
        <div class="init">
            <div class="carousel-container">
                <button class="arrow-left carousel-control" aria-label="Previous image">
                    <img class="next-icon" src="./assets/img/next-icon.svg" alt="next-icon">
                </button>
                <button class="arrow-right carousel-control" aria-label="Next image">
                    <img class="next-icon" src="./assets/img/next-icon.svg" alt="next-icon">
                </button>
                <div class="gallery-wrapper">
                    <div class="gallery">
                        <div class="carousel-item carousel-current-item">
                            <img src="./assets/img/carousel-1.png" alt="carousel-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="./assets/img/carousel-2.png" alt="carousel-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="./assets/img/carousel-3.png" alt="carousel-3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="assets/js/carousel.js"></script>
    </section>
    <section id="about">
        <div class="about">

        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="services">
        <div class="services">

        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

And here is the navbar and carousel CSS:

```css
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: var(--primary-color-grey);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
    
.menu-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
   
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
    
.menu ul li a {
    display: flex;
    height: var(--menu-height);
    padding: 0 2rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
}
    
.menu ul li a:hover {
    background: var(--primary-color);
}
    
#instagram-logo {
    height: 2.8rem;
}
    
.logo {
    height: var(--menu-height);
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
}
    
.hamburguer {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    
.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 0.3rem;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
}
    
@media (max-width: 550px) {
    
    .menu-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: var(--menu-height);
        right: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: var(--primary-color-grey);
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menu-nav:not(.active) {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .menu-nav.active {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .menu ul {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .menu ul li a {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .hamburguer {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .hamburguer.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
 
    .hamburguer.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(0.8rem) rotate(45deg);
    }
  
    .hamburguer.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-0.8rem) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

.

```css
.arrow-right, .arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #0000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
    
.arrow-left {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
    
.arrow-right:hover, .arrow-left:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
    
.next-icon {
    width: 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    
.carousel-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.gallery-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
    
.gallery-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
    
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
    
.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}
    
.carousel-item {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The position: absolute; and position: relative; combination is necessary to ensure the hamburger icon is positioned relative to its containing element, which in this case is the .menu-content.

```
.menu-content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.hamburguer {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

By setting `top: 80px`; and `right: 0`;, you are positioning the hamburger icon 80 pixels from the top of its containing element (.menu-content) and aligned to the right edge. If the `.bars` appears in the wrong location, use the 'right' and 'top' to adjust.

Finally, setting `z-index: 2`; ensures that the hamburger icon will appear in front of other elements on the page, including the carousel, which is usually positioned with a default z-index.

> My suggestion is: ALWAYS CREATE MOBILE FIRST

Instead use a max-width, start using a min-width. I think It's much easier to adapt to a bigger screen then to a smaller screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I still can't get it to work, I put the CSS snippet you sent below `@media (max-width: 550px) {` but the problem still happens...

Comment: Try to delete the "content: ''" and to change the display to "display: inline-block"
Also, take a look on this code: https://github.com/CarlosHenriqueMkt/react-dualshock-sales-page/blob/main/src/App/Shared/Components/NavHeader/styles.ts

I made the same thing you're trying. Analyze and see if you can catch the error.

Comment: Carlos, I think you didn't understood my problem. The hamburguer and NavBar are working very well. The problem is the page content (the image with red color) which is over of the NavBar items when it is open.